# MvvmCross DataService in an Android Broadcast listener

Tags: service, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am currently venturing into the MvvmCross realm and making some good headway, but ran into something that I have been unable to figure out on my own.  I currently have an android service that is going to be running all the time.   That service is going to be started either on a system boot or when the application first fires up.

That service/broadcast receiver will need access to the DataService that is created in a PCL project with MvvmCross.  I have not been able to figure out how to get the instantiated data service into that service/broadcast receiver on creation of the service since there are not any view models that are associated with the service.

I know that it's probably relatively simple, but I haven't been figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably to just request that the full `Setup` is completed during the first part of `OnCreate` for your service:

```
        var setupSingleton = MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable(ApplicationContext);
        setupSingleton.EnsureInitialized();
```

Comment: Ok.  Now that I have it initialized, how would I go about accessing the IDataService object that is only part of the viewmodels?

Comment: Once setup you can access your services using IOC - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control - for any more questions, please ask a new question and include sample code of what you've tried and/or what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Perfect!   Thanks Stuart!   That's what I was missing.   MvvmCross is awesome.   Keep up the good work!