# Mvvmcross IntentService with Dependency Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have an IntentService which is called within my mvvmcross app and on a scheduled basis from an AlarmManager. In the OnHandleInit method of the service I Request a Dependency from Mvx:

```
protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    var ss = Mvx.Resolve<IServerSyncComponent>();
    ss.SyncAll();
}
```

This works fine as long as the Main App is still running. But once the App is killed the code throws a NullReferenceException.

How do I resolve those dependencies?

Comment: does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844889/mvvmcross-dataservice-in-an-android-broadcast-listener help?

Comment: @stuart Yes it helped. Works fine now. If you add an Answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do try/catch to see if ss is null and then not call SyncAll() when it is null.

```
var ss = Mvx.Resolve<IServerSyncComponent()>;
try {
    ss.SyncAll();
} catch (NullReferenceException e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

If I'm not mistaken the AlarmManager will continue to run in the background so you should be suspending or stopping the AlarmManager when you exit the app!

Comment: The whole reason why I use AlarmManager is because it continues to run even if the app is closed. I am no android expert and i used the first thing i could find that worked for me. If there is a better solution than the AlarmManager I am eager to learn it.